# Exclude angular modules

Tags: angular, webpack, webpack-4

Is it possible to exclude `angular` modules with `webpack v4`? I've created custom angular modules, which I want to completely exclude from some builds.

I have for e.g. `MessagingModule`, `TicketModule` in my angular app. Now I need to somehow set-up webpack to exlude those 2.

Any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You have to load your modules conditionally in angular first because if they are loaded in your angular module, webpack have to load them as well.
You can conditionally load modules as given below:
Create a new file which would just contain an array of modules like this:

modules.ts

```
import { ModuleOne } from './one/module-one.module';
import { ModuleTwo } from './two/module-two.module';
import { ModuleThree } from './three/module-two.module';

let Modules = [];

if (production) {
    Modules = [ ModuleOne, ModuleTwo];
} else {
    Modules = [ ModuleOne, ModuleTwo, ModuleThree];
}

export Modules;
```

in App.module

```
import { Modules } from './modules';

@NgModule({
    import: [...Modules], // ... is a spread operator
})
```

Answer (score 0):

try to add them in tsconfig file.

`"exclude": [
    "myexclude.ts"
  ]`